# MVC validating the custom functionality before FormMethod.Post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My MVC view is as follows

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Apply", "Leave", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))`

Any when user submits the form I am calling another validation function

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Apply(LeaveViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid && ValidateLeave(DateTime.ParseExact(model.FromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTime.ParseExact(model.ToDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
   {
        Leave_Data leaveData = new Leave_Data();
        leaveData.Applied_Date = DateTime.Now;
        leaveData.Employee_Id = 1;
        leaveData.Start_Date = DateTime.ParseExact(model.FromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        leaveData.End_Date = DateTime.ParseExact(model.ToDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        leaveData.Leave_Purpose = model.Reason;
        leaveData.Leave_Type_Id = model.LeaveTypeId;
        leaveData.No_Of_Days = model.Days;
        leaveData.Status_Id = 3;
        db.Leave_Data.Add(leaveData);
        db.SaveChanges();
        model = new LeaveViewModel();
        model = GetCommon(model);
        TempData["Result"] = "Success";
   }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TempData["Result"].ToString()))
         return RedirectToAction("ApplyLeave");
     else
        return View();
        }

  public bool ValidateLeave(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
  {
     using (LeaveEntities entities = new LeaveEntities())
     {
        var appliedDate = entities.Leave_Data.Where(s => s.Start_Date >= StartDate && s.End_Date <= EndDate);
        if (appliedDate.Count() > 0)
        {
           TempData["Result"] = "Availed";
           return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
   }
```

I would like to validate this `ValidateLeave()` before submitting the form so that if it is true only I will proceed else user needs to modify his dates

Comment: You can use a `RemoteAttribute`

Comment: Hi Stephen do I need to change it to JSON or will it work with normal functions too?

Comment: `RemoteAttribute` works on model class level, you can use both way (submit form or ajax form).

Comment: Refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx). In your case, apply it to one of the date properties and use the `AdditionalFields` property to pass it and the other date back to a controller method that does the check. The method then needs to return `Json(true)` (valid) or `Json(false)` (invalid)

Comment: How can I apply the same for readonly controls

Comment: @Dotnet, What would be the point? You can't change the value so why would you need to check it?